# How can I send image in subject line in Gmail?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to send an email and it should display subject line like below.

[image]

I tried to put image in subject line but it won't work.
I also googling but unable to find any solution.

Is anyone know how to do it ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**That's an Emoji.**

With the coolness of emoji, a new markting boom is adding emojis to the subject lines of email.

It´s **not** possible to add your own custom images to the subject line.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/using-emojis-and-symbols-in-email-marketing/

**Creating an email message using UTF-8**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

**List of unicode Emojis**

http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: Ok and how to use this in c# ?

Comment: @PranavPatel It's just text characters.  The graphic is simply a result of the email client interpreting the Emoji characters and substituting an image for them.   See ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji

Comment: Reworded Mick's comment, as far as it is an emoji (regular character interpreted in a specific manner) there is no special requirement to make it, just send the mail as you would do usually in c#.

Comment: I wonder how accessible it would be. Fancy, yeah, but blind people or poor vision ones should be able to get info from the subject of the email and emojis will not provide that. Looks to me like a poor decision.

Comment: @bradbury9 Yeah I guess the UX aspect of emojis for disabled people are overlooked.

Comment: Actually the voice over on MacOSX translates the emoji like "Grinning face with wide eyes" - So the accessibility is not all bad.

Answer (score 1):

As you know by now, you're referencing an emoji.  But I just want to share that my own experience using emojis in C# for sending gmail does not require any conversion to UTF8.

In the link provided by Webbanditten, this is presented for the sake of producing some arrows:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Body = "This is a test email message sent by an application. ";
// Include some non-ASCII characters in body and subject.
string someArrows = new string(new char[] {'\u2190', '\u2191', '\u2192', '\u2193'});
message.Body += Environment.NewLine + someArrows;
message.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.Subject = "test message 1" + someArrows;
message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

I don't know if its because I'm working on a .cs file that's saved as UTF-8 already, but I can just cut and paste emojis right in and don't have do deal with `SubjectEncoding` or with character codes.

A modified version of the code below runs successfully and both notepad and visual studio display the actual emoji in the code so it's 'readable'.

```
var hasIssues = true;
var emoji = hasIssues ? "" : "";

using (var client = new SmtpClient("host"))
using (var mail = new MailMessage()) {
    mail.From = new MailAddress("name@from.com");
    mail.To.Add("name@to.com);
    mail.Subject = $"{emoji} Emoji Test";
    mail.Body = "Did it go well?  Check the emoji on the subject line";
    client.Send(mail);
}
```